# Nonacceptance by StackExchange site of Mathematica TeXForm employing \unicode

Tags: latex, unicode

When I apply the Mathematica command TeXForm to

```
DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {9 (1 + \[FormalN])^2 \
\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] - 
      60 (3 + 2 \[FormalN])^2 \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] + (3840 + 4096 \[FormalN] + 
         1024 \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 
     0, \[FormalY][1] == -(9/64), \[FormalY][2] == -(81/4096)}]][bb]
```

I obtained

```
\text{DifferenceRoot}\left[\{\unicode{f818},\unicode{f80d}\}\unicode{f4a1}\left\{\left(10
   24 \unicode{f80d}^2+4096 \unicode{f80d}+3840\right) \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d}+2)+9
   (\unicode{f80d}+1)^2 \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d})-60 (2 \unicode{f80d}+3)^2
   \unicode{f818}(\unicode{f80d}+1)=0,\unicode{f818}(1)=-\frac{9}{64},\unicode{f818}(2)=-
   \frac{81}{4096}\right\}\right][\text{bb}]
```

which was not accepted as the input to `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` in my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322958/compute-the-two-fold-partial-integral-where-the-three-fold-full-integral-is-kno/323011#323011

because the "Argument to unicode must be a number".

I had posed this question first on the TeXstackexchange https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/474568/edit
and was redirected here, although a number of technical responses was given.

Comment: Note that the unicode points (`U+f818` etc..) are in a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas, which means that their interpretation is application-specific and may mean different things to different applications.

Comment: I do not believe that this TeX code is valid. `\unicode` is not defined by default and I was unable to find any package that would define it in such a way that Mathematica's output would get compiled.

Comment: So, Szabolics is this a shortcoming of the TeXForm command? Anyway around it? Is this a bug that should be reported?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a shortcoming of TeXForm. I spent some time on this once, but I was unable to come up with a simple solution even for non-private-use characters.  Notice that `ExportString[Cell[TextData["蔂圃"], "Subsection"], "TeX"]` produces an empty definition of `\unicode`. It might be possible to create a definition manually that can be used with XeTeX (the version of LaTeX that supports unicode) but I do not know how. There is `\Uchar`, but it wants uppercase hex, not lowercase.

Comment: Then there's the much bigger problem that Brett mentioned. The characters you are interested in are private-use, so they would only work with the Mathematica fonts anyway. I think that `TeXForm` is long overdue for an update and it should be able to produce more reasonable TeX code for many of these characters. Not even the new `Association` delimiters are supported, introduced in version 10.0 I think TeXForm stopped getting updates way before then ...

Comment: My complaint about this is CASE:3649408, dated July 2016.

Comment: My best advice to you is to give up on `TeXForm[]` except on simple expression which it can handle. Your expression is beyond its current capabilities. Have you tried doing it yourself **without** the use of `TeXForm`?

Comment: Thanks, Somos! Off-hand, I don't know how to convert the DifferenceRoot formulas into TeX, but I will investigate.